# Python: Merge Values into List for Unique Key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have a list of dictionaries, which contain a key and a value of dictionaries as such:

```
Array = [
    {'Example1': {'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz'} },
    {'Example1': {'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam'} },
    {'Example2': {'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz'} } ]
```

I want to iterate through the list and obtain only unique keys, with the values merged together into one list as such:

```
{ 'Example1': [
    { 'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz' },
    { 'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam' } ] }

{ 'Example2': [ { 'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz' } ] }
```

Any idea on how to go about this? I've tried a lot of different things, but can't seem to get an efficient way to write this code. Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

Array = [ {"Example1": {"Time Taken": 56, "Type": "Quiz"} }, {"Example1": {"Time Taken": 58, "Type": "Exam"} }, {"Example2": {"Time Taken": 40, "Type": "Quiz"} } ]
result = defaultdict(list)
for ar in Array:                 #Iterate each element in list
    for k, v in ar.items():      #Iterate your dict
        result[k].append(v)      #Create key-list.
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Example1': [{'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz'}, {'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam'}], 'Example2': [{'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz'}]})
```

Comment: This is very helpful! If I wanted to put the 'Example1' and 'Example2' into two dictionaries, with their respective list values, can I just iterate through the array 'result'?

Comment: Yes you can. But I don’t see the point. You already have the data in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the dicts and use `dict.setdefault` to set the default as empty list if key is missing and append to the list otherwise:

```
for dct in Array: 
    for k, v in dct.items(): 
        out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

`out` is the desired output `dict`.

**Example:**

```
In [1208]: arr = [ {'Example1': {'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz'} }, {'Example1': {'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam'} }, {'Example2': {'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz'} } ]                                

In [1209]: out = {}                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [1210]: for dct in arr: 
      ...:     for k, v in dct.items(): 
      ...:         out.setdefault(k, []).append(v) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [1211]: out                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1211]: 
{'Example1': [{'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz'},
  {'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam'}],
 'Example2': [{'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
from collections import defaultdict
# l is list of dictionaries
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in l:
    for y in x:
        d[y].append(x[y])
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created following without any external module

```
Array = [{'Example1': {'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz'} }, 
         {'Example1': {'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam'} }, 
         {'Example2': {'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz'} }]

result = {}
for i in range(len(Array)):
    dict = Array[i]
    for key in dict :
        if key in result:
            result[key].append(dict[key]) 
        else:
            result[key]=[dict[key]]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{
 'Example1': [{'Time Taken': 56, 'Type': 'Quiz'},
              {'Time Taken': 58, 'Type': 'Exam'}],
 'Example2': [{'Time Taken': 40, 'Type': 'Quiz'}]
}
```